# String split for street addresses

Tags: python, performance, strings, pandas

I have 856k addresses of pattern:

```
660 1st Ave   New York, NY 10016
```

(with 3 spaces between Ave and New York)

I need to parse and store parts as:

```
Street, City, State, Zip
```

I tried to split through regex but it was super slow, so I went traditional:

```py
def splitAddress(address):
    split = '   '       
    ad = address.strip()

    try:
       if(split in ad):
           addr = ad.split(split)            
           if(len(addr)==2):
                addr1 = addr[1].strip().split(",")
                if len(addr1)==2:
                      addr2 = addr1[1].strip().split(" ")                         

                      if len(addr2)==2:                        
                           return addr[0], addr1[0], addr2[0], addr2[1]
                      else:
                           return "0","0","0","0"                
                else:
                     return "0","0","0","0"                
           else:
               return "0","0","0","0"                
       else:            
           return "0","0","0","0"
    except ValueError as e:
          print(addr[0], addr1[0], addr2[0], addr2[1])
          print(e)
```

I then got the parts as:

```py
df['STREET'],df['CITY'], df['STATE'], df['ZIP'] = zip(*df['ADDRESS'].map(splitAddress))
```

But this is turning out to be pretty slow (it takes 18 mins for 856k addresses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you try implementing your regex?

You can take advantage of panda's str methods to vectorize your regex instead of mapping the function over each element of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(900000))
df["address"] = "660 1st Ave   New York, NY 10016"
```

With a dataframe with 900000 addresses,

```
df.address.str.extract("regex_pattern", expand=True)
```

will extract your regex from each row of the 'address' column in your dataframe.
Something like,

```
df[["street", "city", "state", "zip"]] = df.address.str.extract('(.+)[ ]{3}(.+)\,[ ]([a-zA-z]{2})[ ]([0-9]{5})',expand=True)
```

runs over the entire dataframe in:

> %timeit 
>   7.2 s ± 81.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Basically, you should look for any opportunity to take advantage of panda's vectorized optimizations (string operations, datetime operations, masks, etc.) as described in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods

If at any point you are trying to apply a function to each element in the dataframe/series, stop and check to see if there is already a built-in method that implements what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the education. I originally captured a regex pattern as: address_pattern = r'\w.+\s{3,}\w.*?(,)\s\w+\s\d+'. And then went on to split using re.split in three stages as I did in the function that I wrote above.